# Multiple image upload having issue

Tags: php, image-uploading

I need to write a code were user is able to upload multiple images at once, i have tried out some code but sadly its displaying a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' " am pretty new to multiple upload concept please help me resolve this issue, pardon me if i went wrong somewhere, thank you.

**form.php**

```
<div class="modal-body">
     <form action="multi_upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/><br>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <input type="submit" name="files" class="btn btn-info" value="Upload"/>
     </form>
</div>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','***');
    define('PASS','***');
    define('DB','***');

    $response = array();

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       
        $sql ="INSERT into user_gallery (`vault_no`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`, created_at) VALUES('".$_SESSION['vault_no']."','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type', NOW())";
        $desired_dir="user_data";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
         mysqli_query($con,$sql)        
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' " in what line ? :)

Comment: sorry for that, its in line number 35 of upload.php file.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `;` after `mysqli_query($con,$sql)`

Comment: correct :) http://phpcodechecker.com/

Comment: ooo..i did miss that thanks a ton!

Comment: @KikiTheOne Interesting link. I shall bookmark it.